# Function Generics and type constraints

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the below hierarchy

```
public protocol Entity{
    
    associatedtype T
    
    var id:T  { get set }       
}

open class EntityBase<T>: Entity
{
    public var id:T
}

class Car: EntityBase<Int8>
{
    var test : String
}
```

and the generic function:

```
public func foo<T:AnyObject, Tkey: Any>(id: Any) throws -> T? where T: (Entity){

}
```

What i'm looking for is for the generic function foo to constraint the 'Tkey' type to be the same type as the Entity 'id' attribute type (which will be Int8)

I'm already setting the constraint for 'T' to be an 'Entity' object but how can i constraint the 'Tkey' to be of the Entity's id type?

Comment: With more of the where clause?

Comment: @matt Whatever will be more "correct" as a generic approach yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we for clarity rename the associated type in the protocol

```
public protocol Entity: AnyObject {
    associatedtype IDType

    var id:IDType  { get set }
}
```

Then the function signature can be written as

```
public func foo<ReturnType>(id: ReturnType.IDType) throws -> ReturnType? where ReturnType: Entity
```

Comment: That works thank you!. Do you think this can be written as a where clause without doing crazy restructuring?

Comment: Not sure I understand, what is it you want to be rewritten as a where clause?